# Header appearing in body tag wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I've uploaded a new theme to a wordpress site and the header links and scripts are appearing inside the body tag. I have read that other people have had this problem and I need to save header.php with UTF8 without BOM encoding. However I have tried including 'charset="UTF8-without-BOM' in the files meta tag but still nothing! The website is at : http://rarebreeddigital.com/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check, if the theme has blank string or some simbols before `<!DOCTYPE`, or some functions print string or simbols before `<!DOCTYPE`. If yes, then delete this strings or simbols: `<!DOCTYPE` - must be the beginning of html-document, browsers parser distinguish this line, how parse the document. Then use notepad++ or other rich text editor, open header.php file of theme, then using menu Encoding (in the Notepad++) change encoding to the "UTF8-without-BOM", but meta-tag encodin must be: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`, don't use "without-BOM" here.

Answer (score 0):

I used an **include 'some_other.php';** in my functions.php, and the same thing happened: the header appeared in the body.

I removed the **include**, and copied the code to its place, and voilá - the header moved back to between the head tags.

I couldn't find out what is the problem if I use **include** instead of placing the code in the functions.php, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Wordpress 4.9.4-en_GB.

I fixed it by doing the following:

Set the database's charset to `utf8` and collation to `utf8_general_ci`

Change the encoding for `index.php` and `header.php` file with Notepad++ orany other editor to ANSI or utf8 without BOOM.